# Does request.getRemoteHost() return the IP of browser host?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ip-address

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
    // This scriptlet declares and initializes "date"
    System.out.println( "Evaluating date now" );
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
%>
Hello!  The time is now
<%
    out.println( date );
    out.println( "<BR>Your machine's address is " );
    out.println( request.getRemoteHost());
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

In the JSP code above, I thought `request.getRemoteHost()` would return the ip address of the browser host. However, it returned something like: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's indeed the IP of the machine running the browser, so it'd return `127.0.0.1`, or in your case `::1`, which is localhost in IPv6.

Comment: Also, be mindful of the fact that `request.getRemoteHost()` will return the address of the last *proxy* or client. If you proxy requests to your webapp from Apache HTTP, it may report the Apache server's address, which if it is on the same server as your webapp, could be reported as the localhost, eg. 127.0.0.1 or ::1.

Comment: Yes, and some of these proxies add an "X-Forwarded-For" header, so I typically check for that header first, then as a last resort call getRemoteHost()

Answer (score 13):

**getRemoteHost()**
          Returns the fully qualified name of the client that sent the request.

**getRemoteAddr()**
          Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client that sent the request.

`request.getRemoteAddr()` returns the IP address of the comp whereas `request.getRemoteHost()` tries to retireve the host name. If host name is **empty**, then it tries to retrieve the IP address, just like how getRemoteAddr() works.

[Ref:](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)